# JS Regex to exclude a series of specific numbers

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have a field where I need to collect single number

```
<input type="text" patern="" name="number" required="required" />
```

Now value can be anything 1-9999 however I have some numbers I don't allow, say

```
15
21 
532
```

Is there a regex pattern I can use to force form submission to fail if one of this numbers have been entered?

Comment: How many false matches do you have? This kind of code is generally more manageable as a two-step process, not an all-in-one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?!(?:15|21|532|0+)$)\d{1,4}$/
```

If you look carefully you will see that I included the number `0` in the disallowed list of `15`, `21`, `532`.  The reason for this is that the regex matches any number having 1 to 4 digits, but you only want the range `1-9999`.

Click the links below for a running demo of this regex.

[**Regex 101**](https://regex101.com/r/sR5vM6/3)

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LZf7H/2973/)

Comment: Thank you this works great. P.S. i used to spell **patern** instead of **pattern** that's why none of my attempts ever worked :/

Comment: For some reason cannot make it work at all anymore can you post original code back what was the reason for updating? http://jsfiddle.net/sc79sLop/

Comment: The original solution had a flaw in that it _was_ blocking, for example, the number `15` but it was _also_ blocking `153`, `1503`, etc.  This regex works at least using Regex 101.

Comment: I added my own JS Fiddle link.  The regex is fine.  There must be something going on in your JavaScript code.  Remember to update the Fiddle each time you make a change.

Comment: It wasn't working in pattern property however externally it does work.

Comment: If possible, can provide details of `RegExp` pattern at solution ?

Comment: Your regex is terrible. Just write `/^(?!(?:15|21|532|0+)$)\d{1,4}$/`. I added `+` to `0+`, to prevent `000` from being accepted.

Comment: @nhahtdh Terrible is a relative term.  My answer was functionally correct though it appeared clunky.  Thanks for the sleek update!

Comment: I just realize that it still allows for `015` or `021` to be entered. If those cases are not allowed, then `/^(?!(?:15|21|532)$)[1-9]\d{0,3}$/` should be used instead. It will disallow leading zero altogether.

Comment: Regexp's specified in pattern do not need to be anchored with `^` and `$`. They are implicit. Also, capturing groups are irrelevant in this case, so you don't need to bother with `?:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `type="submit"` to `disabled` if `15`, `21` , `532` value of `input type="number"` , using `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=number]")
var label = document.querySelector("[for=number]");
input.oninput = function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var matches = ["15","21","532"];
  var match = matches.indexOf(val) !== -1;
  this.nextElementSibling.disabled = match;
  this.style.color = match ? "red" : "inherit";
  label.innerHTML =  match ? "Invalid number: <mark style=color:red>" 
                             + val + "</mark>" 
                           : "";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" pattern="" name="number" required="required" id="number" />
  <input type="submit" /><br />
  <label for="number"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont use jquerry in this project you got pure JS solution?

Comment: Your answer has several problems.  First, your implementation makes it impossible to enter certain numbers which contain numbers which should be blocked.  For example, I cannot enter `150`.  Second, he actually wants to block the number `0`, since he stated that he wants the range 1 through 9999.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _"By the way, my answer also has a problem. Can you see what it is? It is actually related to a problem you also have."_ Please enlighten

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can solve 1-9999 by adjusting `type` of `input` to `number` , setting `min` to `1` , `max` to `9999` ; addressing other issues presently

Comment: I chose shorter answer of Tim Biegeleisen as its more straight forward.

Comment: The entire point of the OP's question is that he wants to use the `pattern` attribute and HTML5 form validation, not do everything himself. I also wonder why you provide an HTML snippet which continues to include jQuery, and continues to misspell "patern".

Comment: @torazaburo Removed jQuery , corrected spelling of "pattern" . _"The entire point of the OP's question is that he wants to use the pattern attribute and HTML5 form validation, not do everything himself."_ ? Not certain how this could be inferred from Question ? , e.g., that use of `pattern` attribute is part of requirement of solution ?

Comment: Because he specified the `pattern` attribute in the HTML he provided, and requested a "pattern"?

Comment: @torazaburo _"Because he specified the pattern attribute in the HTML he provided, and requested a "pattern"?"_  Stretching perceived inference for use of `pattern` attribute , and requirement described at text of Question ? Perhaps actually ask OP first , if `pattern` attribute usgae is requirement to be included in Answer ?,  before placing limitation on other users' possible solutions ? Especially where Answer posted by torazaburo does not actually include use of `pattern` attribute ?

Answer (score -1):

```
function isValidNumber(num){
  if (isNaN(+num))
    return false;

  var cant_match = [ 15, 21, 532 ];
  return !( cant_match.indexOf(+num) >= 0 );
}


// Example call
isValidNumber( document.querySelector("input[name=number]").value );
```

Pretty simple:

- `isNaN(+num)` fails if the value passed to the function is something other than a real or whole number (e.g., '32 456' fails)
- the value passed is then checked against the array of bad numbers; if there is an index >= 0, then the number was found in the array

Comment: But the entire thrust of the OP's question was how to use the `pattern` attribute to do the check and thereby use the HTML5 form validation mechanisms to prevent submission (as well as report the error to the user, although he didn't mention that).

Comment: @torazaburo possibly, but he specified JS and RegEx and didn't address the question I left as a comment to his post.

Comment: Because he specified the `pattern` attribute in the HTML he provided?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't understand, are you mad? StackOverflow is about a breadth of solutions, not one single answer. Also, his question used `patern` not `pattern` (with two Ts). This is an important distinction combine that with the fact that he did not tag the question with "html5" and you're making an assumption that may not be accurate. He did not specify how he is performing form validation, which leaves the question open to interpretation.  This answer is not only accurate, but is also easier to maintain if those bad numbers grow and you want to pull them from a server or update them here

Comment: Whoa, slow down. His question says *Is there a regex pattern I can use to force form submission to fail if one of this numbers have been entered, in the case of `<input type="text" patern="" name="number" required="required" />`*? In this case you are not providing a regexp, a pattern, anything that would work with his HTML, a way to use native validation messages which his use of pattern would indicate he has in mind, or a way to prevent the submission. You're welcome to put up any solution you want. However, others are free to comment, or even downvote, preferably without being called "mad",

Comment: @torazaburo It was a question not an accusation; again, you're making assumptions. Second, if there's a list of 1000 bad numbers, or if those bad numbers could change, you'd want to manage them in some other way, other than in a RegEx pattern.  He did not respond to the comment I left. Furthermore, downvoting should be reserved for incorrect answers, not applicable alternative solutions.  By that logic, if you want to be literal about his question then the only answer to an "Is there...?" question is `yes` or `no`, so all answers would be downvoted, since none answer his question - see?