# Matching most but not all one-to-three digit numbers with a PCRE regular expression

Tags: regex, numbers, pcre, digits

I need to match 1, 2 or 3 digit numbers like `([\d]|[\d][\d]|[\d][\d][\d])`. But I need an exception for two 3-digit specific numbers which are `350` and `380`. Is it possible to create a single regex to accomplish my goal?

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't build the exception into the regex, I would just get the match for a 3 digit number, and then if it `== 350 || 380` I would handle that in my code.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing? Sample text + expected output? Sounds like you need `/^(?!3[58]0$)\d{3}$/` or `/\b(?!3[58]0\b)\d{3}\b$/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Regex to exclude some numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271845/js-regex-to-exclude-some-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

- 1 to 3 digits: `\b\d{1,3}\b` (word boundaries are needed here - otherwise you may match part of a longer number)
- Except 350 and 380: `(?!350|380)` or `(?!3[58]0)` if you like less readable expressions ;)

Combine them and you'll get:

```
\b(?!350|380)\d{1,3}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WW2iP6/1)

Comment: *if you like less readable expressions* should be read as *if you like more efficient expressions*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if efficiency is what you're after, then by all means write `\b\d{1,3}\b(?<!3[58]0)`

Comment: I am more fond of cross-platform regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can say 1 to 3 of the same character with {MIN,MAX}. That simplifies your regexp:

```
/^\d{1,3}$/
```

Additionally, unless you want to match `123` from on strings like `12345` you'll want to add some constraints on the front and back, maybe not a digit or a space, comma, etc. In the above the `^` and `$` ensure that the digits are all alone on a line.

Finally, it's probably easiest to just compare the final result with 350 and 380 rather than trying to make a complicated RE. It'll make the final code much easier to read and understand.